# How is the bookmark link feature enabled?

Tags: wiki, hyperlink

For a project I'm working on, I'm trying to setup a glossary of terms in a SharePoint wiki page.  I wanted to be able to link directly to terms but when I tried using regular html # section links, a SharePoint generated javascript function forces the page to the top after every load.  Which makes classic html section linking undesirable.

After reading online, I discovered that Sharepoint duplicates html's section linking with what Microsoft calls **Bookmarks**.  My problem now is that Bookmarks appear to be disabled for our SharePoint site:
[image: This control is currently disabled]

The admins for the SharePoint are ready to flip any switches I instruct them to, but they don't know how to turn this feature on.

How does one activate or authorize bookmarking functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer. To make *Bookmark* field visible, **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** feature (site collection level) must be activated. To enable this field (after previous step it'll be visible but disabled) **SharePoint Server Publishing** feature must be activated (site level).

Comment: I'll try and verify this answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I couldn't verify this, but I"ll accept it.

Comment: This worked for me!