# Adding bookmarks to wiki links

Tags: wiki, hyperlink, wiki-pages

when linking wiki pages on SharePoint you use the `[[page name]]` syntax but is there a way to add a #bookmark to that wiki page link so that the user is taken straight to the desired section of a wiki page?

I know I can just use a standard hyperlink but I was thinking something like `[[page name#bookmark]]` would be much easier!

Does anyone have any good resources for creating wikis on SharePoint 2010? I'd like to read up on all of the possible link options, like `[[list:]]` and `[[view:]]` etc.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like it is possible to add anchors to the SP2010 wiki link shorthand. However, if there is an option to hook a javascript function to your wiki site masterpage, [this SO item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55543/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-anchor-in-a-sharepoint-wiki-page) suggests a javascript that looks for: "/__anchor".

Note the author's comment on how to load the script. Note also, the script uses jQuery.

As for info on links on SP2010 wiki, these seem like good resources for what you are after:

- [Create and edit wiki - Sharepoint Foundation 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-foundation-help/create-and-edit-a-wiki-HA010378208.aspx)
- [Wiki Linking in SP2010](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/05/wiki-linking-in-sharepoint-2010/)