# Link to different sections of the same page

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki-pages, header

I am working on some documentation which will be created using wiki page library. I have been looking into different ways to link to different sections on the same page, I would like to page to scroll down when a link to that location is clicked from an above section. The bookmark option isn't available to me in my SharePoint. Are there any solutions to this with or without code are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The **Bookmarks** / Anchor links feature is available only when [publishing features](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518) are activated. That would be the easiest / no-code way to achieve your requirement If publishing features are allowed in your site.

Tutorial in case you need it: [How to add a hyperlink anchor in a Sharepoint wiki-page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55543/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-anchor-in-a-sharepoint-wiki-page)

If you are not open for this option, I do not think there is another solution to create links to sections on a wiki page.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Comment: @mxcxexlx03 Glad it helps. Would you please vote and accept the reply as the Answer? It can help others find answers quickly in this forum. Thanks.